# In Python how do you make a for loop counting by arbitrary increments?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The in range functionality doesn't work for me:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print str(x)
```

What if I want to count by twos (or other discrete increment)?  In Java or C this is simple, but in Python can you also set the increment of the counter with each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Python has really excellent documentation; did you look at the [`range` function reference](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) at all?

Comment: I was following tutorials like http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop, will check documentation next time.   Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: To be fair, even the simplest questions could deserve a StackOverflow post (that way, they're the first answer when Googled). I can't immediately find an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

range function takes step value as third argument..

```
for x in range(0, 10, 2):
    print str(x)
```